# Is it possible to have multiple grouped "$or" operators on MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's suppose I have this `query` on `MySql`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM myTable
 WHERE field1 = 'Marcelo'
   AND (emit_name = 'Test' OR dest_name = 'Test' OR transp_name = 'Test') -- First "grouped" OR
   AND done = 1
   AND (emit_code = 10 OR dest_code = 10 OR transp_code = 10);-- Second "grouped" OR
```

and my MongoDB aggregate like this:

```
$params['$match']['$or'] = array(
                            ['emit_name' => 'Test'],
                            ['dest_name' => 'Test'],
                            ['transp_name' => 'Test'],
                            ['emit_code' => 10], 
                            ['dest_code' => 10],
                            ['transp_code' => 10]
                        );
```

I would like to do two separated `$or`, one with `emit_name`, `dest_name` and `transp_name` and the other one with `emit_code`, `dest_code`, `transp_code` as the `MySql` `query` looks like, and not only one $or with all the six fields. Is it possible to do with `MongoDB` `aggregation`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.inventory.find( {
    $and : [
        { $or : [ { price : 0.99 }, { price : 1.99 } ] },
        { $or : [ { sale : true }, { qty : { $lt : 20 } } ] }
    ]
} )
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150061/mongodb-multiple-or-operations) may have a better explanation and you may check the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and)

Answer (score 1):

To combine logical conditions under a [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator then wrap the conditions with an [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/) operator.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23307880/9302488) by @NeilLunn you find an example that you can help write the query that interests you.